# How do I turn a Google Photos search result into an album?

Tags: search, google-photos, album

I searched Google Photos for all of my pictures of a person by clicking on the search bar and then clicking on the picture of the person for whom I'm searching.

That worked really nicely — it returns a result with a bunch of pictures of that person organized by date.

Now, I want to create an album so that I can share this batch of pictures with my spouse. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Perform your search
2. Click on the check mark of the first photo so that it is selected
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the batch of photos
4. While holding down the shift key, click the check mark of the last photo

   - Now all of the photos are selected

     - Up to 500; if you have more than that you may need to do this multiple times
5. Click the **+** at the top of the screen (next to where the search bar usually is) and choose "Album"

All of the selected photos are now in an album. Name the album as you like, re-arrange your photos, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Al -- I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of that.  I was looking for a menu option (didn't find) and tried <ctrl>-A (didn't work).  One note: you can only add 500 pictures to an album at a time, so I had to do this in multiple stages because I had > 1,000 search results.

Comment: Good to know. I'll update my answer.